# Can't get the value of closest prev td input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need your help!

I have [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MetCastle/P89Tj/) and what I want is multiplicate  two td's values and the result go to the next td.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "input[id^='unitval']" ).keyup(function() { 

var input_value = parseFloat($(this).val());
var Cant = $("#item_Cant").text(); 
var totval = (input_value * Cant);

    if (!isNaN(input_value)) { // the input is a number
    //$("#totval1").val(totval); // update second field
         $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').val(totval);

    } else { // the input wasn't a number
        $("#totval1").val("not a number?"); // show an error mesage
    }
});
});
```

But just works with the first row because the second one still multiplicating with the td of first row not the actual td

I tried to change the:

```
 var Cant = $("#item_Cant").text();
```

with

```
var Cant = $("input[id^='item_Cant']").text();
```

But don't works, I have not idea why, even first row.

But in this line I need the correct Jquery for get the last td input value in the same tr.

I tried many lines but without success, hope you can understand me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'll start, **ID's are unique** !

Comment: I will try to change identical ids because is a complicated table with php and mysql, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always referring to `item_Cant` ID every time you do your calculation. You need to find the quantity element with respect to your current input field.

Here's one approach that'll work with your current structure:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[id^='unitval']").keyup(function () {
        var input_value = parseFloat($(this).val());
        var Cant = $(this).closest('tr').find('[id^="item_Cant"]').text();
        var totval = (input_value * Cant);

        if (!isNaN(input_value)) { // the input is a number
            //$("#totval1").val(totval); // update second field
            $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').val(totval);

        } else { // the input wasn't a number
            $("#totval1").val("not a number?"); // show an error mesage
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/P89Tj/1/

Comment: @JaredFarrish You can't assume everyone has access to change the HTML. There's a number of reasons why it is not feasible to change the structure of what you have. This is a solution to what has been supplied to the JS developer.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Please actually read the code and realise that there are no duplicate IDs and yes, an attribute selector is required in this particular scenario. Also, your fiddle is broken.

Comment: men, I wasn't unable to do the sum a the bottom of the column with the results, can you help me with that ?  [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MetCastle/P89Tj/) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple identical ids on a page.

Use classes instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "input.unitval" ).keyup(function() { 

var input_value = parseFloat($(this).val());
var Cant = $(this).parent().prev().text(); 
var totval = (input_value * Cant);

    if (!isNaN(input_value)) { // the input is a number
    //$("#totval1").val(totval); // update second field
         $(this).parent().parent().find('.totval').val(totval);

    } else { // the input wasn't a number
        $("#totval1").val("not a number?"); // show an error mesage
    }
});
});

<table width="500" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>VAL1</td>
        <td>RESULT Quantity*VAL1</td>
        <td>VAL2</td>
        <td>RESULT Quantity*VAL2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td><input class="unitval" type="text"/></td>
        <td><input readonly class="totval"  type="text"/></td>
        <td><input class="unitval" type="text"/></td>
        <td><input readonly class="totval"  type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td><input class="unitval" type="text"/></td>
        <td><input readonly class="totval"  type="text"/></td>
        <td><input class="unitval" type="text"/></td>
        <td><input readonly class="totval"  type="text"/></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/8CGXf/